# extract last occurence in path

Tags: regex

I have a path and I need to extract the last dir of 3 chars

```
aa-aaa/123/aaaa -> 123
aaa/123/abc -> abc
aaa/1234/abcd -> aaa
aaa -> aaa
```

This is my 
[try](http://regexr.com/3h99b)

But I am far from an interesting result, if someone has a good regex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This one does the job, you got the dir name in group 1:

```
^(?:.+\/)*([^\/]{3})(?=\/|$)
```

**Explanation:**

```
^
  (?:       : non capture group
    .+      : 1 or more any character
    \/      : slash
  )*        : repeated 0 or more times
  (         : group 1
    [^\/]{3}: 3 non slash
  )         : end group 1
  (?=       : look ahead
    \/|$    : slash or end of line
  )         : end look ahead
```

Comment: Note that this requires lookaheads and that `/` might not need to be escaped depending on your regex flavour.

Comment: At worst, even if `/` is escaped for nothing, it doesn't matter.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation !

Comment: **If** it's a multi line input, like the example, it could match over multiple lines, [like this](https://regex101.com/r/DL8wAK/2). It's unlikely, but it could be avoided by adding `newline` to the negated class.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte one could argue that it makes the regex less maintainable, but yeah I didn't mean to say that the answer was incorrect

Answer (score 2):

If you can use capture groups, this should do it for you:

```
.*(\b\w{3}\b)
```

It skips everything (`.*`) up to the last three word character sequence (`\b\w{3}\b`), which it captures in to group 1.

`\b` ensures a *word boundary* and `\w{3}` is three word characters (i.e. `a-z`, `A-Z` plus `0-9`) (which matches **most** characters allowed in a path. If you need it to match **all**, you'd have to be more specific about execution environment.

[See it here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/DL8wAK/1).

Comment: It doesn't work if directory name has non word character in it.

Comment: @Toto See the comment (last line) in the answer.

Comment: In my case, those are word character, but why, he does not match first?

Comment: @EMottet: In your first example, you have a dash in the first dir `aa-aaa`

Comment: Yes, but in the match I only want word character

Comment: It's hardly intuitive so everyone always forget it, but the `\w` class also contains the `_` character. And at least some flavors will match characters you wouldn't expect when matching unicode, e.g. [these japanese ideographs](https://regex101.com/r/A8KfG8/1). I'd suggest using a character class based on the exclusion of the path separator instead (i.e. `[^/]`), but that won't work with your word boundaries which would have to be replaced by lookarounds.